# Referencing objects programmatically which were set up with Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have set up several Views each containing a UIPickerView each of which contains a UIToolbar, and each of which in turn has a UIBarButtonItem.  All this is set up in IB.  I have pointers to the UIPickerViews in the code.  I am needing to reference the UIBarButtonItems as part of a function that behaves differently depending on which of the UIPickerViews it is dealing with.  I have the (id) sender as an argument to this function.  The sender is always one of the UIBarButtonItems.  I am trying to find which UIPickerView this particular UIBarButtonItem belongs to.  I assume that I have to start up the UIPickerView hierarchy and work down to the UIBarButtonItem.  I think this is the correct approach because I cannot do a simple compare since I have no explicit reference to the UIBarButtonItem object since it was set up in IB.  Further, because the subviews do not have a pointer to their parent view I cannot work my way back up the hierarchy.  Correct?  If I am correct in my thinking to this point, do I: traverse the view hierarchy in each UIPickerView, find a UIToolBar and then find a UIBarButtonItem?  What exactly do I check for at both the UIToolBar level and the UIBarButtonItem level - I mean do I perform an if statement checking to see if the object is of type UIToolBar or UIBarButtonItem respectively? How do I find the type of an object in an if statement?

A related but more general question is should I have just set this entire thing up in code so that I would have had an explicit reference to the UIBarButtonItem that I could have compared the (id)sender against in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out which one it is you need to do two things:

One. In code, add `IBOutlet <object-type> <var-name>` to the `@interface`. For example if you have a UIButton for "pause", you might do

```
@interface blabla {
    ...
    IBOutlet UIButton btnPause;
}
```

Two. In Interface Builder, ctrl-drag from "File's Owner" to the button and select "btnPause".

In the place where you get `(id)sender`, you can then do e.g.

```
if (sender == btnPause) { ... }
```

Comment: @Kalle: can it (bind btnPause<->file's owner) be done "programmatically"? How? (Perhaps you could edit your answer. Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't. Without a reference to the button you have nothing to go by. There may be hacks though, and I'm sure someone will fill you in if there are though I'm not sure why you would want to. If you make it in IB you can just do the linking up as well, no?